# How do you use something other than My Documents for Silverlight 5 Out of Browser?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight 4 supported out of browser support for only the My Documents directory.  I have heard it said the Silverlight 5 now supports other locations.  What other locations can I save to?  Are there any code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With elevated trust you can access just any folder, look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208173/Silverlight-5-Features-Local-File-System-Access-wi) for an example.